# Boost Sort and OpenCL buffer

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, opencl

Can Boost functions, (sort, etc) be operated on arrays that are already in the device buffer?

For instance; I have an array of points in a vbo on the device that I have been operating a kernel function on; I'd like to sort them but avoid pulling all the data back and forth multiple times.

Or is the only option to write a full sort kernel also?

Comment: Does Boost Compute address this?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `boost::compute::buffer(cl_mem m);`

It will take the buffer ownership by default (incrementing the ref). So you can just call `clReleaseMemObject()` on it after passing it. (Or if you are in C++, just let the destructor for cl::Buffer get rid of the reference).

But the real problem is that both contexts should be the same. So you need to set the context of boost to the same context you are using outside of boost. By using `boost::compute::context(cl_context c);`

Again, the ref counter will get incremented automatically, so you can keep using the conetext in the same way, and calling the same `clReleaseContext()`.

After you have that done, you can just call normal boost functions to perform the sorting, etc..

Comment: This sounds pretty much spot on. I'm trying to find a worked example in the boost documentary but no luck; can you point me towards one?

Comment: here looks good? http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost_compute/interop.html#boost_compute.interop.opengl

Comment: Buffer: http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/buffer.html#idp50686528-bb
Context: http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/context.html#idp51913184-bb